# I am trying to figure out how to add images in python 3 and this code is not working also i am doing this on a mac

Tags: python-3.x

I am having some trouble with importing an image in python code on mac can somebody please tell me what is wrong with this code thanks

```
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
my_image = PhotoImage(file='Users/105545/Google Drive/2020/Computing/Victoria Map.png')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=my_image)
```

Comment: is there any errors, warring..etc?

Comment: It errors and says canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
NameError: name 'tk' is not defined

Comment: are you importing `tk` correctly?

Comment: Yeah at least I think so this is what I am using to import from tkinter import *
import os

Comment: You are not importing correctly, just put instead: `import tkinter as tk`